# Is `127.0.0.1` a special token for Ubuntu 14 LTS `resolvconf` when DHCP pushes DNS settings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, resolv.conf, dhcp-option

Dear Linux Graybeards,

Is `127.0.0.1` a magic token for `resolvconf` in Ubuntu 14 LTS when using DNS settings pushed by DHCP?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.0.3 (LTS) in AWS (ami-0f8bce65) with custom DNS settings in my VPC's DHCP Options.  I can push multiple DNS servers via the DHCP options in my AWS VPC to Ubuntu *only* if the values do not include the loopback adapter.

Pushing `127.0.0.1` as a DNS server appears to cause Ubuntu to ignore all subsequent name servers.

## Working Example - Without loopback as a nameserver

For example, if I configure the DHCP options to use `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`, and `AmazonProvidedDNS` (e.g., `172.24.0.2` in my VPC), I see this in `/etc/resolve.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 172.24.0.2
```

## Broken Example - With loopback as a nameserver

However, setting the DNS servers as `8.8.8.8`, `127.0.0.1` and `AmazonProvidedDNS` results in:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

The expected value `172.24.0.2` is missing in the second example.

## AWS DHCP Behaving As Expected

I confirmed this is *not* an AWS issue with their DHCP server.   `dhcpdump` confirms the DHCP server is responding with `8.8.8.8,127.0.0.1,172.24.0.2` as the DNS servers:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-24-0-13:~$ sudo dhcpdump -i eth0 &
[1] 1742
ubuntu@ip-172-24-0-13:~$ sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-24-0-13
sudo dhclient -v eth0
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-24-0-13
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/0e:fa:a9:1e:38:c1
Sending on   LPF/eth0/0e:fa:a9:1e:38:c1
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xd6248a3f)
DHCPREQUEST of 172.24.0.13 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3f8a24d6)
DHCPOFFER of 172.24.0.13 from 172.24.0.1
DHCPACK of 172.24.0.13 from 172.24.0.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 172.24.0.13 -- renewal in 1361 seconds.
ubuntu@ip-172-24-0-13:~$   TIME: 2015-11-18 20:38:09.837
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (e:fa:a9:1e:38:c1) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: d6248a3f
  SECS: 0
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 0e:fa:a9:1e:38:c1:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  12 ( 14) Host name                 ip-172-24-0-13
OPTION:  55 ( 13) Parameter Request List      1 (Subnet mask)
                         28 (Broadcast address)
                          2 (Time offset)
                          3 (Routers)
                         15 (Domainname)
                          6 (DNS server)
                        119 (Domain Search)
                         12 (Host name)
                         44 (NetBIOS name server)
                         47 (NetBIOS scope)
                         26 (Interface MTU)
                        121 (Classless Static Route)
                         42 (NTP servers)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  TIME: 2015-11-18 20:38:09.839
    IP: 172.24.0.1 (e:56:f6:92:57:f3) > 172.24.0.13 (e:fa:a9:1e:38:c1)
    OP: 2 (BOOTPREPLY)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: d6248a3f
  SECS: 0
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 172.24.0.13
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 0e:fa:a9:1e:38:c1:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         2 (DHCPOFFER)
OPTION:  54 (  4) Server identifier         172.24.0.1
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      3600 (60m)
OPTION:   1 (  4) Subnet mask               255.255.255.240
OPTION:  28 (  4) Broadcast address         172.24.0.15
OPTION:   3 (  4) Routers                   172.24.0.1
OPTION:   6 ( 12) DNS server                8.8.8.8,127.0.0.1,172.24.0.2
OPTION:  12 ( 14) Host name                 ip-172-24-0-13
OPTION:  26 (  2) Interface MTU             9001
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you are going to use `127.0.0.1` then you really should ONLY use `127.0.0.1` and setup forwarders in your DNS server.

Comment: @Zoredache Agree that makes sense, but, I have a corner case for a few nodes where a local resolver/forwarder isn't possible.  Technically, I should be able to specify a list of nameservers, right?  If the first, `127.0.0.1`, isn't reachable, resolv should carry on to the next nameserver in the list, right?

Comment: Brilliant answer below but I *really* can't see a use case for anything other than the AWS-provided resolver inside a VPC.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Use case is running Consul.io for service discovery.  Consul provides dynamic DNS, binding to the loopback adapter.  The AmazonProvidedDNS is a fallback during boot before Consul is online.  I also have a few 3rd party appliances running Ubuntu LTS that I can't modify to run the Consul agent, thus the corner case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is 127.0.0.1 a magic token for resolvconf

I don't have an Ubuntu 14 system available, but it is 'magic' on most versions of resolvconf.

Specifically in the file `/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc` there is a variable `$TRUNCATE_NAMESERVER_LIST_AFTER_LOOPBACK_ADDRESS` that if left at default, will result in the loopback superseding any other setting.  If Bind, or DNSMasq is on your system and is setting the `127.0.0.1` that name server gets applied very highly in the resolvconf interface order and you almost always will have `127.0.0.1` only.

If you want to change this behavior try creating the file `/etc/default/resolvconf` and setting `TRUNCATE_NAMESERVER_LIST_AFTER_LOOPBACK_ADDRESS=y`.

Comment:  Wow, thank you!   I just went to school and it was good!